# Espaçamento com colunas bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

Estudando o site oficial, vi que o **cool-xs-offset** foi implementado somente a partir da versão **3.0.1**, sendo assim inclui a versão **3.0.3** em meu site.

**Problema**

O que acontece é que quando eu aplico o **xs-offset** (conforme exemplo abaixo), ele aplica também para os demais aparelhos esse offset. Não teria como aplicar somente aos XS ?

```html
<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-sm-4">
```

Comment: Você pode adicionar um exemplo do problema?

Comment: Guilherme, os exemplos estão no topico. O que acontece é que ele considera esse espaçamento para todos os aparelhos e não somente aos 'XS'

Comment: Olá Tiago. Como no caso do Guilherme também não consegui entender o problema. Você poderia cria um [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) e compartilhar o link demonstrando o problema para nós? Para usar o Bootstrap basta incluir http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css em *External Resources*.

Comment: Vamos la. Não tem como eu montar o exemplo do modo correto, pois no jsfiddle ele ja reconhece o espaço utilizado como sendo um aparelho 'XS', então não tem como eu montar o exemplo desejado http://jsfiddle.net/N7nrE/ . A unica coisa que eu gostaria, é que o offset do xs não interferisse nos offset do sm, md e lg.

Comment: Fiz um codepen exemplificando.
Não detectei o problema, porém eu utilizei a última versão: 3.1.1 http://cdpn.io/diubq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**'Solução'**

Consegui resolver o problema somente aplicando os demais offset, isso está correto ?

```html
<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-offset-0 col-xs-8 col-sm-4">
```

Comment: Como você disse, é uma solução também, não que seja a mais correta, porque era para ele funcionar para `xs` apenas...
Uma pergunta, você mudou por acaso o tamanho do container?

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa colocar:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-offset-0 col-lg-
offset-0 col-xs-8 col-sm-4">
```

Basta colocar uma vez o `offset-0` que vai por herança até o final.
Ficaria assim:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 (a partir daqui o "0" fica igual para md e lg) 
col-xs-8 col-sm-4">
```