# Grid Sytem Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando usar o Grid System do BootStrap, porem não consigo.
Li essas duas perguntas:
[Como funciona sistema de grid?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8894/como-funciona-sistema-de-grid), 
[Espaçamento com colunas bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2397/espacamento-com-colunas-bootstrap).
Segui exatamente o que foi respondido, porem ainda assim não funciona.
Renderiza um e baixo do outro, não ao lado.

Realmente deveria renderizar assim??
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Segue código: [Js Fiddle - Grid System](http://jsfiddle.net/Franckcf/ghpVa/)

Answer (score 1):

Você importou os arquivos CSS do Bootstrap? (Não encontrei no seu exemplo)

O Twitter Bootstrap funciona com um CSS que contem uma coleção de classes e mixins para ajudar no desenvolvimento.

Caso você ainda não tenha conhecimento sobre como utilizar, basta importar o arquivo *bootstrap.min.css* e *bootstrap.min.js* no seu HTML para que todos os componentes funcionem perfeitamente. Estes são encontrados para download no próprio site da ferramenta: getbootstrap.com

Comment: Sim @Diego Lopes Lima, importei da seguinte forma.
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: @FranckCosta Está apontando para o local correto da folha de estilo?

Comment: Se você estiver fazendo testes direto no jsFiddle a explicação para estar quebrando linha pode ser apenas o tamanho do frame em que o script está rodando.

Eu apenas editei o seu script e quando eu almento o tamanho do frame de resultados ele se comporta perfeitamente.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghpVa/3/

O bootstrap faz com que as colunas (col-md-?) quebrem linha em determinada resolução para se adaptarem melhor a dispositivos com telas pequenas.

Comment: @Diego Lopes Lima estou utilizando localmente mesmo, não estou fazendo uso do JSFiddle para testar o Bootstrap.

Comment: Realmente não tem o por que não funcionar então. Neste exemplo que editei está funcionando perfeitamente, creio que só poderia dar algum erro caso a importação dos arquivos retorne erro 404, ou de permissão de leitura do arquivo...

Comment: @Laerte esses são os caminhos dos meus arquivos.
`Pasta Raiz: C:\Users\inhome\Desktop\IE\testBoot`,
`index: C:\Users\inhome\Desktop\IE\testBoot\index.html`,
`BoostStrap: C:\Users\inhome\Desktop\IE\testBoot\bootstrap`,
`href:  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">`,

Ao adicionar a class `container` ele atribui a margem como explicado na documentação, porém, não muda nada ao colocar `row` e depois como filho `col-md-?`

Comment: Qual é a largura em pixels do seu monitor?

Comment: @Diego Lopes Lima 1280X1024,esta é a resolução.

Comment: Não tenho como afirmar, mas se o seu viewport estiver com uma largura igual ou inferior a 992px, o Bootstrap quebra as colunas a partir desta largura. Pode verificar?

Comment: @DiegoLopesLima vou verificar e já te respondo, caso a informação seja útil, ao utilizar o `class="span6"`, ele deixa uma do lado da outra.

Comment: Então já sei, você provavelmente está usando a versão 2 do Bootstrap, baixe a versão 3 (a mais atual), pois a nomeclatura de algumas classes foram alteradas nesta versão.

Comment: Caso queira continuar com a versão 2, use esta documentação: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: @DiegoLopesLima agora funcionou, era o problema de versão mesmo, agora esta lado a lado, fico muito grato pela ajuda de todos.